# Is save method mandatory in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
Model.find(ids).each { |model| model.is_active = false } unless ids.empty?
```

Here, is model.save method necessary or not ? Because without that also, it's working.

Column is defined like this

```
t.integer :is_active, limit: 1
```

Comment: Depends on how `is_active=` is implemented. You say that it is working without calling `save` explicitly, so `is_active=` seems to persist the changes itself.

Comment: t.integer :is_active, limit: 1

Comment: Well, ActiveRecord doesn't persist changes to a model right away (that would result in countless database queries). Something else must be going on and it's outside your above code.

Comment: tinyint to boolean transformation has  something to do here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: Yes.

Running `model.is_active = false`, by itself, will not *persist the change* in the database. Try re-fetching the database record after running `model.is_active = false`, and you'll see that the value has not actually changed; you also need to run `model.save` to do that.

However, for scenarios like this (assuming you want to immediately save the change to the record!) there's a more concise way of saving the data, instead of running two commands:

```
model.update_attribute(:is_active, false)
```

This will update the value in the database, if validations pass, and also run any callbacks (e.g. `after_save`).

If you want to update the value **without** running validations and callbacks (which is typically faster, but more "dangerous") then you can instead use:

```
model.update_column(:is_active, false)
```

Comment: Yes, these commands will work. I wanted to know how my code is working already. Is boolean to tinyint transformation has internal save command ?

Comment: Tom hints on this, but here's a very clear example: Let's say you're a student, and you get a transcript of your grades from your school. Then, you carefully change one of your grades on the transcript for a better grade. Your transcript is updated; but unless you sneak into the school and copy your transcript back into the official register, your grade will not have changed. Your DB model is the school records; your variable contents is the transcript. As long as you don't reload, you'll have the updated copy; but if you request a new one (without having saved), you get the "official" record.